# How to add a title to an amcharts map?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, amcharts, amcharts4

I currently have a map that uses the [amcharts](https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v4/chart-types/map/) library.  Everything looks great right now, but I want to add a title to the top of the map (i.e. the top left corner).  I tried scouring the docs, but couldn't find any help for maps (not charts).  Any tips/suggestions are appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use this.

```
let title = chart.titles.create();
title.text = "Speed";
title.fontSize = 25;
title.marginBottom = 30;
```

you can see more about it here [Titles amCharts](https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v4/tutorials/adding-chart-titles-and-bottom-text/)